# How to programmatically assign a keyboard shortcut to open an Edge Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm trying to program an Edge extension, and I would like the extension to open when I press a keyboard shortcut (for now, I want to use Ctrl-B).  I found a way to assign a keyboard shortcut after I install the extension, by going to edge://extensions/shortcuts and then using the Microsoft GUI to assign the keyboard shortcut.  But, I want to do this via code.  I've tried the following snippets in manifest.json and popup.js, but they don't work.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
.....
  "commands": {
      "openExtension": {
          "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Ctrl+B"
          },
          "description": "My description"
      }
  }
.....


....
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    if (command === 'openExtension') {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'openExtension'});
    }
});
....
```

Comment: It's the user's decision, not yours. Maybe that's why it's not supported. But there is also an [issue](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/14809) about that.

Comment: I have an extension (that I bought, I didn't program myself) that has a built-in shortcut to open the extension.  There must be some way to do it; they did it.

Comment: Okay, did you check how they do it? Look at their manifest and such.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we only need to use `_execute_action` to define the shortcut to open the extension. For example, you can add below code in manifest.json:

```
"commands": {
      "_execute_action": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+5",
          "mac": "Command+Shift+5"
        }
      }
  },
"permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ]
```

Then you'll find it works and automatically shows in edge://extensions/shortcuts.

Please note that not all keyboards combinations will work, I suggest you use `Ctrl+Shift+[0..9]`. You can also refer to [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/commands#scope):

> Keyboard shortcut suggestions for global commands are limited to `Ctrl+Shift+[0..9]`. This is a protective measure to minimize the risk of overriding shortcuts in other applications.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I tried a couple of different keyboard shortcuts, and neither worked.  I also looked at that doc you linked to, to no avail.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+5` doesn't work either? It's strange, it works on my side, it will open the extension popup.